# Calling Javascript function from another file 'Cannot read property of undefined'

Tags: javascript, html, function, office-js

I have taken an example from the Word.js documentation [Here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Add-in-JavaScript-PersistCustomSettings/blob/master/PersistCustomSettingsWeb/App/Home/toast.js), but I cant get similar code to work in my project. I am trying to call a method in one js file from another. My method is written as the following.

```
var Toast = (function () {

    var ToastDiv = "divToast",
        Success = "success_notif",
        Notice = "",
        Output = "";

    function showSuccessToast(title, message) {

        if (document.getElementById(Success) == null) {
            createToast();
        }

        document.getElementById(Notice).innerText = title;
        document.getElementById(Output).innerText = message;

        $("#" + Success).animate({ left: '12%', }, 500);
        setTimeout(function () {
            close();
        }, 2000);

    }

    function close() {

        e.preventDefault();
        var parent = $(this).parent('.toast');
        parent.animate({ left: '110%', }, 500);

    }

})();
```

In  `Home.js`, in the same directory, I then wish to call the `showSuccessToast` method like the following:

```
Toast.showSuccessToast("","");
```

In the `Home.html` file I have linked the javascript like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="toast.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Login.js"></script>
```

However I still get the error `Cannot read property 'showSuccessToast' of undefined`.
This is the first time I have used this syntax of defining the Toast method, so I'm not sure where I've gone wrong here. How can I call the showSuccessToast method?

Comment: `showSuccessToast` is not a property of `Toast`. It's just a function that exists within the scope.

Comment: How is it used this way in the example?

Comment: I do not see anything in your code which makes a function of on js file to be visible in another js file.

Comment: Im trying to use a similar syntax to that of whats used in the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your Toast IIFE is not returning anything. It should return the function. Add below code in your Toast IIFE and it will work.

```
return {
    showSuccessToast: showSuccessToast,
    close: close
};
```

When its getting called, Toast is not exposing any function as no functions are returned. So Toast is undefined. As a result you're getting this error..

Answer (score 0):

try add return { showSuccessToast: showSuccessToast } in your Toast function